# Shopping Price rules, Stop Further Rules Processing change

Tags: magento

We've just upgrade our site from Magento 1.4 - 1.9. The Shopping Price rules have stopped working.

Each rule only applies to the first product of the cart, not the entire cart, if Stop Further Rules Processing is set to "yes" which it used to be.

It only works on the whole cart when this Stop Further Rules Processing is changed to "no".

This means that all our multi rules now don't work as it run both. For example:

20% off 12 items, Stop Further Rules Processing set to "no", gives 20% off but also gives 10% off, a later rule, which used to not apply. We only want to give 20%.

20% off 12 items, Stop Further Rules Processing set to "yes", gives 20% off only the first item in the basket and ignores the rest.

Any ideas how we get it to look at the whole basket but then not process any other rules?

Cheers,

Harry

Comment: To better help, can you post all of the  fields and their values for the conditions and actions sections of the rule?

Answer (score 2):

I've found it online, there seems to be a fundamental problem in 1.9 -
https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix

This worked for us, but make sure you re-index and fully flush the cache